# identifying repeating numbers or number patterns in php

Tags: php, regex

I've seen quite a few question on SO about identifying repeating patterns for crazy looking strings and stuff but nothing that will capture a repeating number or a repeating number pattern.

I'm trying to figure out a way to write a function that can identify both of these cases. For example I have a number pattern similar to `14285714285714` with the pattern being `142857-142857-14`. In some cases the pattern could be say, `7575757` : `75-75-75-7`. I also have a reoccurring number like `55555555` or `55555556`.

How could I go about creating a function that determines if a number is either repeating or has a pattern? I guess the repeating number could be seen as a pattern in that sense. I'm kind of at a loss on this and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** i also only need to throw true if the pattern or re occurrence is longer than 3 digits.

**UPDATE** So I tried @stribizhev recommendation with preg_match and was indeed able to detect a pattern. I still need my pattern to be much more precise though. If my number is `4444` preg_match shows my pattern as `44-44`. I need to be able to know the difference in `4-4-4-4` and `75-75-75`. Can some one help me clarify how I would get a more precise result from the preg_match?

Here's what I have so far.

```
 $num = 4444;
 if (count($num) >= 3) { 
    $result = preg_match('/(\d+)\1/', $num, $matches);
    if ($result) {
       $repeat = "true";
       echo "match: ".$matches[0].", ".$matches[1]; 
    }
 }

 output: match: 4444, 44
```

Although this output isn't inaccurate, It's just not as specific as I need it to be. 44 is the pattern, but even more so 4 is the pattern. Just like in 7575, 75 is the pattern.

Comment: What about a simple `'/(\d+)\1/'` or `'/^(?=.*(\d+)\1)/'`? Could you please clarify your EDIT?

Comment: would i do that with preg_match?

Comment: First you need to be clear about what you are looking for. For example `55555555` can give `5555-5555` or `55-55-55-55` or `5-5-5-5-5-5-5-5`. In this case what pattern do you want to extract?

Comment: Well with 55555 I need to extract the single number pattern. if my number is 757575 I would need the 2 digit number pattern. I updated my question with my preg_match attempt as well.

Comment: Why is `5` single though? Those could be fifty fives, five hundred fifty fives, etc.

Comment: Anything else that would trail off the pattern would need to be stored as well so I can know what it is. For example `5555567` patern is `5-5-5-5-5` and trailing is `67`

Comment: @chris85 in this use the repeating 5's are just 5's and not 55's. Only if the 2 digits are different from each other. So with repeating 5's the single value is important and with repeating 75's the 75 is important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern does the job:

```
$pattern = '~
    \A    # start of the string
      # find the largest pattern first in a lookahead
      # (the idea is to compare the size of trailing digits with the smallest pattern)
    (?= (\d+) \1+ (\d*) \z )
      # find the smallest pattern
    (?<pattern> \d+? ) \3+
      # that has the same or less trailing digits
    (?! .+ \2 \z)
      # capture the eventual trailing digits
    (?= (?<trailing> \d* ) )
~x';

if (preg_match($pattern, $num, $m))
    echo 'repeated part: ' . $m[0] . PHP_EOL
       . 'pattern: ' . $m['pattern'] . PHP_EOL
       . 'trailing digits: ' . $m['trailing'] . PHP_EOL;
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB4kY1/1)

Comment: This is outstanding! Thank you!