# R - Why does my regex code only pull patterns with an even cycle of repeats?

Tags: regex, r

Inspired by trying to find the longest pattern for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155662/find-and-break-on-repeated-runs/33161687#comment54153122_33161687) question.

This may be a very basic regex question, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around capturing repeated groups.

**Setup**

Let's say I have 5 cycles of `"1234"` nested in a character string.

```
x <- c(rep(1:4, 5), c("56"))
x <- paste0(x,collapse = "")
x
"1234123412341234123456"
```

I want to extract the largest (defined by largest extracted string length) pattern in the string. This would be `1234` x 5.

My thought would be:

- Capture group of >=1 character length: `(.+)`
- Find cases where this group repeats >=1 times: `\\1+` (Note, in R we have to escape the `\`character).

**My full expression:** `(.+)\\1+`

But when I try this:

```
str_extract(x,"(.+)\\1+")
[1] "1234123412341234"
```

I only get the `1234` x 4. My thought is that it finds the largest match for the `(.+)` that also has a repeat. Since `12341234` has a repeat (x2), it overrides the `1234` x 5, even though the overall matched string is larger.

My regex is not advanced, and I was unable to find any documentation on why this was the case. Is there a theory that I am missing? Is this possible in regex?

Comment: *"Is there a theory that I am missing?"* yes, the theory about how quantifiers work. Try to find a tutorial about greedy/non-greedy quantifiers and about the backtracking mechanism. Perhaps look at regular-expressions.info or rexegg.com

Comment: Try on https://regex101.com/ to see how the regex work and follow @CasimiretHippolyte advice above

Comment: Whatever, it isn't a trivial problem. I answered a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875163/identifying-repeating-numbers-or-number-patterns-in-php/32876178#32876178) for PHP (but regex engines are the same).

Comment: I just can't understand what exact expected output is for `1234123412341234123456`?

Comment: @stribizhev it would be the longest total character string made up of a repeated pattern - `1234` repeated 5 times. Regex picks up `12341234` repeated twice because the sub-pattern is longer. My understanding from the above comments is that this is not really something regex will be able to accomplish easily, as I now have a better understanding of how regex "thinks"

Comment: If you do not need the count, just the longest repeated substring, try Casimir's solution. It should work since R can use Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default, regex is greedy: it tries to match for as long as possible. When you write this:

```
(.+)\\1+
```

The sub-pattern is `12341234`, which is double of what you expects. Use a `?` to make it non-greedy:

```
(.+?)\\1+
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the repeated part is something like `1123`, your pattern will return `1` with a string like `1123112345`